# How do I parse values in a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I've created a hash to read in mime types and extensions. I'm having trouble trying to parse multiple entries like this jpeg line:

```
image/png    png

image/jpeg   jpeg jpg jpe
```

My code reads this into a hash with the mime types being the key and the extensions as values as follows:

```
def initialize(mime_file_content)
      @mime_file_content = mime_file_content
      @hash = Hash.new
      @mime_file_content.lines.each do |pair|
        pair.chomp!
        next if pair.empty?
        next if pair.include? "#"
        key,value = pair.split(" ",2)
        @hash[key] = value
      end
end
```

The png line outputs fine:

```
key: image/png 
value: png
```

The jpeg outputs:

```
key: image/jpeg
value: jpeg jpg jpe
```

I can't figure out how to separate the multiple jpeg extension values so I can assign them to the image/jpeg key. I tried doing a second split:

```
@hash.each_value {|value| value.split(" ")}
```

That didn't work. Is there any way to split multiple values on one line and assign them to the same key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use splat

```
key,*value = pair.split(" ")
```

to produce hash like this

```
{"image/png"=>["png"], "image/jpeg"=>["jpeg", "jpg", "jpe"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
@hash.each {|k, v| @hash[k] = v.split}
```

Or more directly, in your code, change the line:

```
@hash[key] = value
```

to

```
@hash[key] = value.split
```